# Must read resources for NoSQL developers

Tags: database, nosql

Can you recommend any resources every NoSQL developer should be familiar with?

Comment: mynosql: http://nosql.mypopescu.com/

Comment: About cap: http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.com/2010/04/problems-with-cap-and-yahoos-little.html

Comment: Why no joins: http://www.dbms2.com/2010/05/01/ryw-read-your-writes-consistency/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice link collection to databases, forums, articles and other resources:

http://nosql-database.org/

Answer (score -1):

one of the "must read" resources for a developer, NoSQL or not, is "the source code"